# Highlight matching text filter javascript

Tags: javascript, html, typescript, stenciljs

I'm doing a search filter highlight. But it renders `[object Object]` instead of `<mark>match values</mark>` when replacing the values.

Currently I have this code.

```
this.countries.response.filter((val) => {
  const position = val.value.toLowerCase().indexOf(this.controls.country.toLowerCase());
  if (this.controls.country == "") {
    return val;
  } else if (position !== -1) {
    return val;
  }
}).map((e) => {
    const position = e.value.toLowerCase().indexOf(this.controls.country.toLowerCase());
    let matches = e.value.substring(position, this.controls.country.length + position);
    const regex = new RegExp(matches, 'gi');
    const highlighted = e.value.replace(regex, '<mark>'+{matches}+'</mark>');
      return (
        <li class="lov-val list-group-item">
          <p>{highlighted}</p>
        </li>
    )
})
```

And I am having this output.
[image]

I'm doing something like this.

[image]

Comment: matches is an object, thats why you cant print it out. If you console.log(matches), im sure you'll figure out what you want to print out.

Comment: Can you make a little jsfiddle or something to demo?

Comment: The `e.value` refers to the object response in the map. Not the element dom target.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're seeing `[object Object]` because you're appending an object to your string with `{matches}`. You should do something like `'<mark>' + matches + '</mark>'` so that you append a string instead.

However that probably won't fix the issue. I suspect you'll still see the string `'<mark>EXAMPLE_TEXT</mark>'` in your output instead of actual html. This is because text content containing valid html is just interpreted as text, the browser won't parse it as html.

It looks like you're writing `jsx`, so I'm assuming you're using React. An easy fix would be to use the [dangerouslySetInnerHTML](https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml) prop. However there are security concerns with using this (hence the cautious name) so use it at your own discretion.

I don't have an immediate alternative at mind, but I imagine there should be some way to break up each country string into separate components without having to use `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` and regex replace shenanigans.

e.g.

```
<span>
  <span>
    SOUTH
  </span>
  <mark>
    AME // this is the part that's highlighted
  </mark>
  <span>
    RICA
  </span>
</span>
```

Comment: I also did this one but its not rendering the html tag instead it is rendering something like this `<mark>AF</mark>GHANISTAN`

Comment: `const highlighted = e.value.replace(regex, '<mark>' +matches+ '</mark>');` i did something like this one.

Comment: In my second paragraph I describe why you're seeing this issue, please read through the whole answer and hopefully it makes sense.

Comment: yup my bad. I'll check the link you provided. Thanks

Comment: I already fixed the issue. Thank you. I cast it inside innerHTML instead.

Answer (score 1):

I've done something like this:

HTML

```
<div>
    <form>
      <input type="text" id="input" oninput="filter_list()" placeholder="search..." />
    </form>
   </div>
       <div class="list overflow-auto">
         <ul class="list-group">
            <li class="list-group-item">Elephant</li>
            <li class="list-group-item">Kangaroo</li>
            <li class="list-group-item">Monkey</li>
            <li class="list-group-item">Snake</li>
            <li class="list-group-item">Zebra</li>
            <li class="list-group-item">Panda</li>
         </ul>
       </div>
```

CSS

```
.yellow{
  color: #ebae00;
}
```

JavaScript

```
let input = document.querySelector('#input');
let list = document.querySelector('.list .list-group').querySelectorAll('li');

function filter_list() {
  let result = new RegExp(input.value, 'i');
  list.forEach((item) => {
    if (result.test(item.textContent)) {
      item.innerHTML = item.textContent.replace(result, '<b class="yellow">$&</b>');
      item.style.display = 'block';
    } else {
      item.style.display = 'none';
    }
  });
}
```

If you want to see the code working, here is my CodePen code: [Highlight text filter](https://codepen.io/marlonmnz/pen/mdxBxOq)

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing all your code, I suspect you are only missing one step. You get an HTMLCollection. You have to iterate this and enclose the match - as you already did correctly - with mark.

Here is an example that makes it even clearer for you.

```js
const term = "c"
const countries = document.querySelectorAll("#countries div");    

for(let i = 0; i < countries.length; i++) {  
  countries[i].innerHTML = countries[i].innerHTML.replace(new RegExp(term, "gi"), (match) => `<mark>${match}</mark>`);  
}
```

```html
<div id="countries">
  <div class="item">USA</div>
  <div class="item">China</div>
  <div class="item">Canada</div>
</div>
<div id="output"></div>
```